# I want to integrate my ASP.Net application with quickbooks enterprise, is the integration similar for desktop enterprise as it is for online with IPP?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, qbxml, qbfc

I want to integrate my asp.net application with quickbooks enterprise.

I have done integration with quickbooks-online using IPPV3 ASP.net; I can send HTTP calls with JSON objects to get response, but now my requirement is to connect my asp.net application with quick books enterprise software.

Can I use that approach for quick books enterprise which I have used for quick books online?

Please help me with respect to my knowledge as I have done work with online (small scale) version.

Comment: Please add what research you've done already on desktop integration and why that research has proved inconclusive.

Comment: @Muhammad Atif Agha .. I want to integrate my asp.net application with quickbooks enterprise... i am trying the same i need some one told me the steps ..

Answer (score 0):

> Can i use that approach for quick books enterprise which i have used for quick books online?

No. There is no REST API for QuickBooks Enterprise.

You need to use the QuickBooks Web Connector, along with the QuickBooks SDK.

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0020_get_set_up/sdk_downloads
- http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector

Comment: What about IPP? Can't we use its REST library for communication with Quickbooks desktop?

Comment: No, IPP *does not support* QuickBooks desktop anymore. There *is not a REST API* for QuickBooks desktop anymore.

Comment: I want to integrate QuickBooks enterprise version, and that is only desktop version as QuickBooks Online does not have enterprise edition.

Comment: Again -- for QuickBooks Enterprise, use the Web Connector. I have included links in my answer above. The Web Connector is the only way to integrate a .NET application with QuickBooks Enterprise.

Comment: Thanks, can you also provide me any link to how to add qwc file in web connector because whichever link i have explored, they used to advise to register some file on some store, i am not sure what does it mean.

Comment: To add a .QWC file to the Web Connector, click the "Add Application" button in the Web Connector. Choose the .QWC file when prompted. Click OK. It's not any more complicated than that. If you continue to have trouble, post the .QWC file so we can help you further.